# Cake PHP3 validate rest API header parameters

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm developing REST API with cake PHP3 for the mobile application. 
Every request header has custom parameter call `X-App-Key` for the verify mobile app. (Unique ID for the app - X-App-Key : '123456789')

I need to check that parameter value before give access to API endpoints.
How do it check from `bootstrap.php` or any other place. (in controllers).

Can this use cakephp `Dispatcher Filters` for validate and filter requests ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `Dispatch Filters` would be a good option here. If your application is going to serve browser requests as well, controller would be better. For Dispatch Filters, you can do it like :

1) config\bootstrap.php

```
DispatcherFactory::add('ApiHeader');
```

2) src\Routing\Filter\ApiHeaderFilter.php

```
namespace App\Routing\Filter;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter;

class ApiHeaderFilter extends DispatcherFilter
{

    public function beforeDispatch(Event $event)
    {
        $request = $event->data['request'];
        $xAppKey = $request->header('X-App-Key');
        if ($xAppKey != '123456789') {
            // throw exception or message
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use `TableRegistery` for database query :

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
...
$tableModel = TableRegistry::get('table_name');
$xAppKeys = $tableModel->find('all', ...
```

Reference Links : 
[Request Headers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#working-with-http-methods-headers) & 
[Dispatch Filters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html)